# SpiderMonkey compilation error

Tags: javascript, c++, spidermonkey

I've just installed the latest version of SpiderMonkey and am trying to run the sample "Hello World" program for embedding the JS engine. The sample program is shown below:

```
    #include "jsapi.h"

/* The class of the global object. */
static JSClass global_class = {
    "global", 
    JSCLASS_GLOBAL_FLAGS,
    JS_PropertyStub, 
    JS_DeletePropertyStub, 
    JS_PropertyStub, 
    JS_StrictPropertyStub,
    JS_EnumerateStub,  
    JS_ResolveStub, 
    JS_ConvertStub
};


int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
      JS_Init();

    JSRuntime *rt = JS_NewRuntime(8L * 1024 * 1024, JS_NO_HELPER_THREADS);
    if (!rt)
        return 1;

    JSContext *cx = JS_NewContext(rt, 8192);
    if (!cx)
        return 1;

    JS::RootedObject global(cx, JS_NewGlobalObject(cx, &global_class, nullptr, JS::DontFireOnNewGlobalHook));
    if (!global)
        return 1;

    JS::Value rval;
    bool ok;
    {
      JSAutoCompartment ac(cx, *global); 
      JS_InitStandardClasses(cx, *global);

      const char *script = "'hello'+'world, it is '+new Date()";
      const char *filename = "noname";
      int lineno = 0;
      ok = JS_EvaluateScript(cx, *global, script, strlen(script), filename, lineno, &rval);
      if (rval.isNull() | rval.isFalse() )
        return 1;
    }

    JSString *str = rval.toString();
    printf("%s\n", JS_EncodeString(cx, str));

    JS_DestroyContext(cx);
    JS_DestroyRuntime(rt);
    JS_ShutDown();
    return 0;
}
```

However, I am getting the following errors(when I compile with g++ on terminal):

```
js/src/helloworld.cpp:21:53: error: use of undeclared identifier 'JS_NO_HELPER_THREADS'
js/src/helloworld.cpp:36:25: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'JSAutoCompartment'
js/src/helloworld.cpp:37:7: error: no matching function for call to 'JS_InitStandardClasses'
js/src/helloworld.cpp:42:12: error: no matching function for call to 'JS_EvaluateScript'
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't give the include path and library path while compiling.

You should compile in this way:

> sudo g++ -std=c++11
>   -I/home/pi/mozjs-24.2.0/js/src/build_OPT.OBJ/dist/include  -L/home/pi/mozjs-24.2.0/js/src/build_OPT.OBJ/dist/lib/ HelloWorld.cpp -o Helloworld -lmozjs-24 -lz -lpthread -ldl

where `HelloWorld` is the name of your file.